# How to create to classes which is using each other in different files?

Tags: c++, class

For example I have a class A defenition

```
class A {
 ... 
 }
```

in a.h

and B in b.h

```
class B {
 ... 
 }
```

in a.h I need `#include "b.h"` and in b.h I need `#include "a.h"` but it's recursive fault for compiler.

I can trick it in one file with pre defention like that

```
class A;
class B {
     ... 
     }
class A {
     ... 
     }
```

but for clarity... I want to separate them from each other, how can I make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forward declarations is the way to go:

```
//B.h
class A;
class B
{
};
```

and

```
//A.h
class B;
class A
{
};
```

Note that this won't work if you need a full type, i.e. a data member of type `A` or `B` is needed by the respective other class (method parameters, return types, pointers or references would work with an incomplete type).

Comment: At least one of the class can have full type when you include either of them to another header.

Comment: @iammilind it can, but if it's possible, forward declarations should be preferred.